# "hideCol" command hides the column, but also hide it from edit form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a grid that shows data from a "users" table. In that grid I don't want to show some fields such as "password", so I have hidden them from the grid, but the problem is that they also get hidden from the form and of course I need the user to be able to set it.

Any way to solve this?

Thanks

Jaime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `edithidden: true` property of [editrules](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#editrules).

Answer (score 0):

Use a **context selector**

```
$('.password', $('#grid')).hide();
```

So if all your password fields have a class called `password` , then using the context makes sure only the elements with the class will be searched inside the context will be hidden , and the one's in the form will not.